# How do I make make a block summon an explosion using onEntityCollidedWithBlock? Minecraft Modding

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make my block summon an explosion when a player or mob collides with it. So far, I can make it damage them, but not trigger an explosion. Does anyone know how?

Here is my code:

```
package com.icearrow26.moreapples.blocks;

import com.icearrow26.moreapples.Main;
import com.icearrow26.moreapples.init.ModBlocks;
import com.icearrow26.moreapples.init.ModItems;
import com.icearrow26.moreapples.util.Interfaces.IHasModel;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.block.state.IBlockState;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityMinecart;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemBlock;
import net.minecraft.util.DamageSource;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.Event;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

public class TNTBase extends Block implements IHasModel{
    public TNTBase(String name, Material material)
    {
        super(material);
        setUnlocalizedName(name);
        setRegistryName(name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.BUILDING_BLOCKS);

        ModBlocks.BLOCKS.add(this);
        ModItems.ITEMS.add(new ItemBlock(this).setRegistryName(this.getRegistryName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void registerModels() {
        Main.proxy.registerItemRenderer(Item.getItemFromBlock(this), 0, "inventory");

    }
    public void onEntityCollidedWithBlock(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, Entity entityIn)
    {
        entityIn.attackEntityFrom(DamageSource.IN_WALL, 1.0F);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code: https://pastebin.com/dmX9Je5P

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what problems are you encountering. The question is too vague.

Comment: I believe that you need to make an `ExplosionEvent`, register it, and then call `ExplosionEvent.start()`

Comment: @sorifiend That would be wrong. Events are "I DID A THING! (does anyone want to know about and/or modify it?)" not "SYSTEM: DO THE THING."

Answer (score 3):

## Step 1: Always ask yourself "does vanilla do something like this?"

In this case, yes, Vanilla creates explosions. Not when an entity collides with a block, but that's just a *when* it does it, not *how* it does it. In this case, `EntityTNTPrimed` is the class we want.

In it we find this method:

```
private void explode()
{
    float f = 4.0F;
    this.world.createExplosion(this, this.posX, this.posY + (double)(this.height / 16.0F), this.posZ, 4.0F, true);
}
```

Voila. Now we know how to make explosions. Copy, paste, invoke when we want it to happen. No step 2 needed.

## Now, some other things...

These are common issues I see all the time and should also be corrected.

1. `IHasModel` is stupid. **All** items need models and all of the information necessary to register a model is public. Using interfaces like this is an anti-pattern and you picked it from a Youtube tutorial making this a [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) practice. You do not need it at all ever. Just call `ModelLoader.registerCustomModel()` directly in your `ModelRegistryEvent` handler

   - "I need to go through my proxy!" you say. Your *`ModelRegistryEvent` handler should already **be** in your client proxy.* The `ModelRegistryEvent` class is client-only.
   - I can probably even tell you what YT video you watched and link you directly to my comment telling its author that `IHasModel` is stupid. If I'm wrong I'd go and *make* a comment.
2. `TNTBase` tells me you also have a `BlockBase` class somewhere that most of your blocks extend (or this is that class). This is another antipattern: using inheritance for code reuse.
3. You do not own icearrow26.com, so you should not be using that as your package identifier (Minecraft uses `net.minecraft` because they *own* Minecraft.net!) You should use `mod` instead of `com` or omit it all together.
4. You almost certainly have a `CommonProxy` class. This is stupid. Common code can go in your **main mod class.** The whole point of the proxy system is to *distinguish* client from server and allow code that can only be called on one side to be called on the one side without crashing the other with unknown references. Common code can go anywhere, it does not need a proxy.

[More information](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/61757-common-issues-and-recommendations/)